# Need a help in solving an equation (probably differentiation)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find out the interference condition between tool and a part. The below attached snapshot is the equation between interference and machine feed. At dy/dx = 0, I will have max. interference, which I intend to find. Except x and y every alphanumeric character in the following equations is a constant.

I tried to get it in y = f(x) format, however because the constants and y are so complexly attached,  I failed. It would be of great help, if someone can help me find out an equation that gives me the dy/dx = 0 condition. Thanks.

[image: equations]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: *Except x and y every alphanumeric character in the following equations is a constant.* In the first equation, $x$ is a combination of constants?  That would make it constant as well.